# Каким образом можно "достать" с консоли массив аргументов в NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, консоль

Kаким способом можно получить в Node.js с введенных в консоль строк-комманд их массив для подальшей обработки(например, в switch'aх)?

Пример команды в консоли:

```
create Vasya Pupkin 03-06-1989 musician
```

(допустим, надо распарсить ее и к примеру, создать такой объект)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В npm есть пакет [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist), предназначенный для парсинга аргументов коммандной строки. Установить его можно:

```
npm install minimist или yarn add minimist
```

такой код

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.dir(argv);
```

при таком вызове

```
create aaa bbb -f -g=45
```

выведет

```
{ 
 _: [ 'aaa', 'bbb' ],
 f: true,
 g: 45
}
```

при вашем вызове

```
create Vasya Pupkin 03-06-1989 musician
```

вывод будет такой

```
{
 _: [ 'Vasya', 'Pupkin', '03-06-1989', 'musician' ]
}
```

в котором все параметры находятся в виде строк в массиве в поле _

Comment: я так понял, это работает только при запуске программы. Нужно же вводить команды во время исполнения. Если не прав, поправьте.

Answer (score 0):

Я делал что то подобное через метод. Я думаю это то, что ты хотел.

```
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});
```